# how to make camera brightness full while capturing an image

Tags: java, android

Can anyone tell me how can i make camera brightness full while capturing an image .I am opening camera activity using implicit intent in main activity so is there anyway by which i can make the brightness full when i launch camera app, and after taking the picture i want to make the brightness as it was before launching the camera app
 i have tried this  code -

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layout = getWindow().getAttributes();
        layout.screenBrightness = 1F;
        getWindow().setAttributes(layout);
but it does not give the right thing
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use either the `setWhitBalance()` method or the `setExposureCompensation()` method.